# StructureMap Setter Injection not setting property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am trying to setup setter/property injection for my MVC project using StructureMap, but I can't seem to get it to set the properties. I am well aware that Constructor injection is the recommended practice, but I have a strict requirement that requires we do it using setter injection, so please hold the comments attempting to tell me otherwise.

I have the normal boilerplate setup code such as the following in my Global.asax

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new TestControllerFactory());

ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => {
            x.For<IPaymentService>().Use<PaymentService>();
            x.ForConcreteType<HomeController>().Configure.Setter<IPaymentService>(y => y.PaymentService).IsTheDefault();
            x.SetAllProperties(y =>
            {
                y.OfType<IPaymentService>();
            });

        });
```

My TestControllerFactory looks like the following:

```
public class TestControllerFactory:System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected  IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerType");
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController ;
    }
}
```

I have the following Service/Implementation class pair

```
public interface IPaymentService
{

}

public class PaymentService:IPaymentService
{

}
```

And finally, I have my controller that will have the property that needs to have the concrete payment service implementation injected into it:

public class HomeController:Controller
{
     public IPaymentService Service {get;set;}

```
 public ActionResult Index(){
        var test = Service... //Service is Null
 }
```

}

Shown above, the property remains null when I debug.

Additionally, I have tried using the [SetterProperty] just to see if it worked(I have no intention of coupling my controllers with those attributes), and it still didnt work.

I am not sure if I need to do something else, or what the problem might be. I have been using constructor injection with StructureMap for quite awhile.

Comment: Did you have any luck with Setter Injection? I'm trying in on Action Filters but it doesn't seem to work also.

Comment: After struggling to work with setter injection, I decided to move away from it.

Answer (score 3):

Try dropping this line:

```
x.ForConcreteType<HomeController>().Configure
  .Setter<IPaymentService>(y => y.PaymentService).IsTheDefault();
```

It shouldn't be necessary.

Given the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IMsgService Service { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(Service.GetMessage());
    }
}
```

This was all that was required to configure StructureMap to set the property:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.For<IMsgService>().Use<MyMsgService>();

    cfg.SetAllProperties(prop =>
    {
        prop.OfType<IMsgService>();
    });
});

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
```

Comment: This solution just works if the property is in a `controller` class , in my case the property is `non-controller` class so your answer wouldn't help me.

Comment: It should not make any differences *providing* you have configured StructureMap with all the dependencies in the object graph.

Comment: I put my property `IUnitOfWork` in my controller and it gets the value but when I put it in another class `MyServiceFactory` and instantiate the `MyServiceFactory` class in my controller the `IUnitOfWork` property is `null`.

Comment: If *you* instantiate `MyServiceFactory` then StructureMap will not resolve any dependencies. You either need to make `MyServiceFactory` a dependency of your controller or call `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MyServiceFactory>` within your controller.